# Swift animate with duration not taking duration into account

Tags: ios, swift

The frame is getting updated in 0.2 seconds or so, rather than the desired amount (0.5). When I try 5 seconds it still goes the same speed of around 0.2 seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my entire method:

```
@IBAction func photoFullscreenButtonReleased(sender: AnyObject) {
    photoFullscreen = !photoFullscreen

    if photoFullscreen {
        contentHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height

        animateUpdateConstraints()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(5) {
            self.previewLayer!.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
        }
    }
    else {
        contentHeightConstraint.constant = contentHeight

        animateUpdateConstraints()

        UIHelper.delay(0.25, closure: { () -> () in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
                self.previewLayer!.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Potential function that could be causing problems?

```
func animateUpdateConstraints() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: previewLayer is an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer - Is there I way I can add it in storyboard?